# AT+CUSD Not Working on modem Huawei e3131a

Tags: putty, at-command, modem, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to send at commands to get balance on huawei e3131a modem but i always receive "Ok" as answer no matter the configuration i use (GSM, IRA, UCS2). I also tried to change the operator code (`#123#`) to many formats like Hex PDU Simple String but no way to get the balance.
Here is the command i sent : 
`AT+CUSD=1,"#123#",15`.
Thanks in advance for the help.

NB: I am using Putty to send commands.

Answer (score 7):

**I finally found the method to send USSD At commands.**

Some 3G Modem doesn't support plain text or even hexadecimal form.
So to send commands I have to set the modem to IRA form by doing:

`AT+CSCS="IRA"`

After I convert the command that permits me to get balance (for me : #123#) to **gsm7bit** form.

Finally sending the command by doing:

`AT+CUSD=1,"A3986C3602",15`

It will return OK the first time and 5 seconds after, it returns the response in gsm7bit form.
It exactly returns:

`+CUSD: 1,"4379999CA683CEECB738CCD68162351CCDC81ABFDB707AB92E07C9CB6374587E2E8362351CCD080A83C66FF7FCDD6E97E5A0B03DECA683D86510CCF682E55E3258ECE6A286E1653D080682BFEB7210BB0C2297E9E1345B470ED3CB207219640FB3D3E434BD0C2AD341EDB79B1E76D341E432688C0EC7EB65D0F8DD86D3CB75B92B5A4FD3E965B92E06",15`

And to get it in plain text just copy and convert to string.

Thanks to all !!

Comment: JAVA gsm7bitEncoder : https://github.com/bsimic0001/AegisWallet/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/aegiswallet/utils/MessagingUtils.java

Comment: Tried yout way...Itsent with OK but response never came back...Any idea what I should do ?

Comment: Jason Krs... were you ever able to resolve it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: On-line encoder/decoder: http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288

Comment: @JasonKrs you need to setup a ussd listener to get the response.

this library will help -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport-gsm

  POC:
 ```
            modem.on('onNewIncomingUSSD', (data) => {
                console.log('onNewIncomingUSSD ', {
                    data
                });
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation the AT+CUSD command will return OK immediately if all the parameters are correct. If the first parameter is set to 1, an unsolicited response (+CUSD:...) will be returned when the network responds to the USSD request.

So you must wait for +CUSD response after you have received an OK.

Comment: Ok! But as response to my command i only receive 
+CUSD:2
Instead of my current balance!

Answer (score 1):

first run this : `AT+CSCS="IRA"`

goto http://www.rednaxela.net/pdu.php

alphabet size: 7

enter USSD code (eg. *124#)   , click convert

in the 2nd box, copy the last line

add it to your ussd section:  `AT+CUSD=1,"AA988C3602", 15`

after getting the output in 7bit (CUSD=1,"xxxxxxxxxx..7bit"), copy it

goto http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/topic.php?id=288

in the "USSD Entry/Display" section, select GSM 7bit packed

paste the result you had from the modem

click convert

if you want to do this programatically, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ussd-pdu-text-converter