# Communicating with GSM modem with AT Command

Tags: c#, at-command, ussd, gsmcomm

I am trying to communicate with GSM modem through serial port in c#.

So far i have been able to connect with it,send AT command to it and send SMS.

for SMS sending,i am sending the following AT command

```
AT+CMGF=1 /* set text mode */

AT+CMGS=8801911xxxxxx 

"hellp msg "+ (char)26
```

its working as expected.

But for sending USSD message,

im trying

```
AT+CMGF=0 /* PDU mode */
AT+CUSD=1,*121# , 15
```

But its returning no response.

I have tried with GSMCOMM library,it has no response as well.

I have tried to convert the text to PDU, still no luck.

So how can i send USSD message in C# in a serial port to a modem and get the response back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send USSD command like this:

`AT+CUSD=1,"*121#",15`

Also please note `AT+CMGF` affects only SMS sending, not USSD.

You might also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700301/atcusd-not-working-on-modem-huawei-e3131a).

Comment: actually i was sending exactly this, but still no luck.
Here is how im sending and receiving :

           _serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=1,\"*121#\",15");
             Thread.Sleep(1000)
              result = _serialPort.ReadLine();

am i need to do anything extra to get USSD response ?

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700301/atcusd-not-working-on-modem-huawei-e3131a)?

Comment: No,The link has solved my problem.

can you post it as answer so that i can accept?

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam i've edited my answer. Please don't forget to also upvote original answers so that you help the others!

Answer (score 0):

**Send USSD command like this:**

```
sp.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"*710#\",15\r");
```